# Tableau calculating variances (division) of two calculated (countif fields)

Tags: tableau-desktop

Tableau is giving me a hard time, trying to compare two items by percentages.  I need to display the percentage different between the number (couintif) of string items based on condition.

Basically, I wrote two calculated fields like:

Calc field #1
IF [Outcome] = "Complete" Then 1 Else 0

Calc field #2
IF [Outcome] = "Pending" Then 1 Else 0

and a third field to get the percentage of pending sales to completed sales

Calc percentage

SUM(Calc field #1 / Calc field #2)

But it's not working.  The first two fields work fine, validated them with dataset, but the third calculation doesn't work and always outputs 0

Answer (score 0):

The formula for **Calc percentage** should be

`SUM(Calc field #1) / SUM(Calc field #2)`

As both the calculated fields are computed row-wise, it is important to aggregate while using it in a formula.